Is Eisenstein's theorem on irreducibility a necessary condition for irreducibility?
I thought about this question when I came across a question about proving reducibility of a polynomial (prove that the polynomial $x^6+5x^2+8$ is reducible over the integers).
What is the general way to approach such questions (if any)?

Actually the question was to prove it was REDUCIBLE. I thought about the same thing but unless the question is wrong I can't figure it out
